# Pipe symbol executes from left to right or right to left?

Tags: scripts

How pipe symbol executes from left to right or right  to left?

```
ls -l | grep "Aug" | sort +4n
```

So first `ls -l` will be executed or `sort +4n` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipe will execute the commands from left to right. So `ls -l` would be executed first.

```
command 1 | command 2
```

Ouput of first command is feded as input to the second command.

```
$ ls -l | grep "Aug" | sort +4n
```

`ls -l` command would be executed first. Then it's output is passed as input to the next command `grep "Aug"` after that the ouput of `ls -l | grep "Aug"` command is passed to the last command `sort +4n` as input.